# How to Convert Uploaded Audio to Blob using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, file-upload, blob

I am trying to capture the audio that's uploaded by the user, convert it to Blob then using wavesurfer.js to display the waveform.

I am following this instruction here https://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/62e747cea7af01542479

And here is the code

```
// Convert audio to Blob
  $('#audioFileInput').on('change', function () {
    var file = $('#audioFileInput')[0].files[0];
    var fileName = file.name;
    var fileType = file.type;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
      var arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
      blobUtil.arrayBufferToBlob(arrayBuffer, fileType).then(function (blob) {
        console.log('here is a blob', blob);
        console.log('its size is', blob.size);
        console.log('its type is', blob.type);
        surfTheBlob(blob);
      }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
```

But it says

```
blobUtil.arrayBufferToBlob(...).then is not a function
```

Another issue is that since the user might upload the audio themselves, the audio type might vary, expected to come from native device audio recorder. Anyone can help please? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `File` object, like the ones you get in the `input.files` FileList, is already a Blob:

```js
inp.onchange = e => 
  console.log(inp.files[0] instanceof Blob) // true
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

So all you really need is to pass directly this File to your library:

```
$('#audioFileInput').on('change', function () {
  var file = this.files[0];
  surfTheBlob(file);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer already.

```
// Convert audio to Blob
$('#audioFileInput').on('change', function () {
    var file = $('#audioFileInput')[0].files[0];
    var fileName = file.name;
    var fileType = file.type;
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        return response.blob();
      }
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    }).then(function(blob) {
      surfTheBlob(blob);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
    });
  });
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know might be old topic but there is simpliest way to do that:

```
const blob = new Blob([file], { type: file.type })
```